# tasker read numbers one by one

Tags: tasker

I am using this task to say loud numbers from SMS:

```
Variable Section: %SMSRB From 1, Length 6, Store Result in %SMSNUM
Variable Search Replace: %SMSNUM (?!^), Replace Matches, Replace With ,
Variable Split: %SMSNUM, Splitter ,
Say: %SMSNUM(1), Pitch 5, Speed 6, Respect Audio Focus
Say: %SMSNUM(2), Pitch 5, Speed 6, Respect Audio Focus
Say: %SMSNUM(3), Pitch 5, Speed 6, Respect Audio Focus
Say: %SMSNUM(4), Pitch 5, Speed 6, Respect Audio Focus
Say: %SMSNUM(5), Pitch 5, Speed 6, Respect Audio Focus
Say: %SMSNUM(6), Pitch 5, Speed 6, Respect Audio Focus
```

It's working and my question is if there is more elegant way how to read number from SMS. If I wouldn't split it, it'll automatically read number as whole (thousands, hundreds, etc ..) and I want to have number read/said one by one. Also, I've noticed that there are pauses between numbers and I cannot find why, can it be configured ?